# How to do a "continous display" in QGIS like in TileMill?

Tags: qgis, tilemill

In TileMill the "Earth" was automatically displayed "continuously", which means there was no "end". I tried to find this option in QGIS now, but nor search not checking through the options, etc. brought any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible in QGIS. The reason is related to projections, TileMill only supports Web Mercator projection, which preserves north/south. Up is always north, down is always south.

This is required to allow the wrapping that you see in TileMill or Google Maps.

QGIS supports all map projections, a very large number of which don't preserve north/south alignment so it's not really practical.